# How to get access to variable that is assigned in function that is inside other class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I want to get access to an variable from function that is inside other class. How can i do it? I've tried multiple "possible" solutions, but I cant still find it out.

```
class Class(object):
    def assign(self):
        self.result = 'passed'

print(Class.result)
print(Class.assign().result)
```

Comment: Your `assign` function is an instance method that creates an instance variable, but you are never instantiating an instance of `Class`, so that variable does not exist anywhere...

Comment: Going off of what @juanpa.arrivillaga said, you also can't access the `result` attribute from the return value of `assign`. You would need to do something like: `instance = Class()`, then `instance.assign()`, and finally `instance.result`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Class(object):
    def assign(self):
        self.result = 'passed'
        return self.result

object = Class() 
print(object.assign())
```

this code return the `self.result` variable

Answer (score 0):

To access the attribute you first need to create an instance of the class, then execute the method in order to create the attribute and finally you can access it:

```py
class Class(object):
    def assign(self):
        self.result = 'passed'

obj = Class()
obj.assign()
print(obj.result)
```